# Erratic behaviour with layer backed/layer hosting NSViews

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, calayer, nsview

I have a view hierarchy that looks like this:

[image]

So basically I have an NSSplitView with a subview that contains a scroll view (for a table view) as well as a footer view that contains 3 subviews. Some important things to note:

- Uses the 10.8 base SDK, **no auto layout**
- The window content view, the split view, the parent view of the scroll and footer views, and the scroll view and footer view are all **layer backed** with an **NSViewContentsRedrawOnSetNeedsDisplay** redraw policy.
- The `NSClipView` of the `NSScrollView` is a special subclass that is a **layer hosting** view and uses a `CAScrollLayer` as the backing layer.
- The *Color View* is a simple layer backed view that has a background color set.
- The *Background View* is a **layer-hosting** view that has a sublayer with the *contents* property set to an image (**contentsCenter** is also set)
- The *Content View* is a **layer backed** container view that contains a single subview, a custom **layer backed** button view (not an NSButton).
- The footer view overlaps the scroll view by about 3 pixels

I'm getting pretty erratic behaviour with this layout. Here are the three distinct scenarios I'm getting, which randomize every time I launch the app.

1) Everything appears OK. Background view and all the content are there:

[image]

2) The button appears fine, but the Background View seems to be partially transparent:

[image]

3) Background View appears properly but the button is gone:

[image]

There is absolutely no code that is changing between each of these scenarios. I just stop and run the app again. I made sure that I'm not changing anything related to opacity at runtime. The only thing I do at runtime is set the background colors and images on the views.

**EDIT:** I had a feeling that the overlapping views might be causing trouble, so I tested without the overlap and get the same results.

**EDIT 2:** This seems to be a problem with the `zPosition` of the layers of the layer backed views. The order is scrambled and random. If I manually force the zPosition of the layers to the right values to match the subview order, then everything is fine. Unfortunately, I can't find a cleaner way to do this than just setting the `zPosition`.

Comment: Are you running a Beta of OS X?  I've had some pretty terrible experiences with layers and layer-backed things under the 10.8.3 beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an OS X bug. [A radar has been filed](http://openradar.appspot.com/13542277). In the meanwhile, here's the best workaround I found (where `view` is the superview of all of the sibling views):

`view.subviews = [view.subviews copy]`

Triggering the setter for `subviews` sets the proper `zPosition` on the view layers.